# Subtracting a string from an integer

Tags: python, string, integer

So I’m teaching myself python online using ‘Programming with Mosh’ on Youtube. I’m looking at type conversion, and Mosh is discussing how you cannot subtract a string from an integer.

However, when I ran my program as per his tutorial, it actually works perfectly without crashing. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

This is the code I used, and according to his tutorial this should generate an error.

```
birth_year = input("Enter your birth year: ")
age = 2022 - birth_year
print(age)
```

Comment: What is the output you that you get after you enter your birth year? Or do you mean it doesn't crash immediately after you run the script?

Comment: Are you still using Python 2 by any chance?